# How can I grant permission to API Gateway to invoke lambda functions through CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I've been all over the web searching for an answer to this.

Essentially, we're spinning up an API using Swagger, which is awesome and works great, but one thing doesn't work... When we make a call to an Endpoint, we get a 500 error (it's not a 500 error that we're providing either it's one from AWS). The error states "Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function" (https://youtu.be/H4LM_jw5zzs <- This is a video, from another user, of the error I'm getting).

I've gone down many ratholes, and have found an answer... It involves using the AWS CLI and looks a bit like this:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name FUNCTION_NAME \
--statement-id STATEMENT_ID \
--action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:API_ID/*/METHOD/ENDPOINT"
```

This is great and all, but we are using CloudFormation to spin up everything and we want this to be automated. Is there an easier way to go about this? Is there something in CloudFormation that will give us the resource policy that we need?

I'm hitting a bit of a wall with this, but I've been working on it for a few hours today and it's a bit of a blocker for our API release, so any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also do this via AWS SDK too. I use it for Go, so it's here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#Lambda.AddPermission ... What I don't see if any way to list existing permissions. So I just tolerate the errors about it already existing in my deploy tool. Weird. I mean I didn't even see anything about needing this permission either and it's not in any exported Swagger either.

Comment: I believe you can **add a role to the API Gateway with permissions to invoke the required Lambdas**. I'm still looking for how to do that but I believe this should be a better solution than continually adding these fiddly permissions policies to the Lambdas.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a `CloudFormation` solution to this problem. See the following `CloudFormation` snippet:

```
"Permission": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties": {
        "FunctionName": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Lambda", "Arn" ] },
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
        "SourceArn": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
            "arn:aws:execute-api:",
            { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ":",
            { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" }, ":",
            { "Ref": "API" },
            "/*/*/*"
        ] ] }
    }
}
```

This grants `API Gateway` permissions to launch your `Lambda` function. Variables in this snippet you need to change are `Lambda` (line 4) and `API` (line 11).

Comment: Is there any danger doing `"/*/*/*"` versus `/*/POST/example`? on the face of it, it seems like we are opening up permissions for that api end point to call any resource path

Comment: @David it all depends on the application - whether or not you need the API Gateway to be a filter

Comment: for all FunctionName which should I use?

Comment: i need to give permission to all my lambda so what should I put under FunctionName??

Comment: You can see it's an ARN. Inspect it and you may be able to put "*" at the end where the function name is.

Comment: Anyone else feel like this resource should be automatically created in the SAM translation based on the API/Lambda-event bindings? Anyone seen the requirement for manual creation of this resource documented by AWS anywhere?

Comment: In SAM this should be automatically handled by the Api resource. @rainabba

Answer (score 6):

For the invoke permissions:

```
    "APIInvokePermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties": {
    "FunctionName": {
      "Ref": "YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_RESOURCE_NAME"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "SourceArn": {
      "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${YOUR_REST_API_RESOURCE_NAME}/*/*/*"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: i need to give permission to all my lambda so what should I put under FunctionName??

Answer (score 5):

Thanks https://twitter.com/edjgeek for helping me get this straight in my head.

This GIST shows how to use AWS::Serverless:Function with Events to automatically generate the needed AWS::Lambda::Permission to allow APIGateway (for a given route) to invoke your Lambda:

https://gist.github.com/rainabba/68df1567cbd0c4930d428c8953dc2316

Both of the following approaches assume an api such as (many fields omitted for readability):

```yaml
  MyApi:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      DefinitionBody:
        Fn::Transform:
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: openapi.yaml
```

## Using "SAM Events"

The most relevant bit (I've omitted many required fields):

```yaml
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Events:
        MyRouteEventToProxy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: POST
            Path: '/some-route/{pathParm}'
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi # ResourceName of AWS::Serverless::Api
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
```

## Using "openapi binding"

If you'd rather declare the binding in the openapi.yaml, then see the following project (no Lambda/Events required). This approach requires an explict role to allow invoke.

*template.yaml relevant bits:*

```yaml
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      # Events: # No need for Events when binding from openapi.yaml
  MyHttpApiRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
```

*openapi.yaml relevant bits:*

```yaml
paths:
  post:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: POST
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyLambdaFunction.Arn}:live/invocations"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: aws_proxy
        credentials:
          Fn::GetAtt: [MyHttpApiRole, Arn]
```

https://github.com/aws-samples/sessions-with-aws-sam/tree/master/http-api-direct-integration